# Writing a function to automatically sort numbers into 256-unit chunks?

Tags: c#, byte

I have a programme in *Unity* which connects and talks to a custom exe file. I need to send the exe file values up to potentially around `12000` (although the max I can is about `65500`).

The data needs to be separated into two chunks - | units up to `256` | number of `256`'s |

Some examples:

If I wanted to send a value of `1000`, it would be "**+ 232 + 3**" (`3 * 256 + 232`)

If I wanted to send a value of `4878`, it would be "**+ 14 + 19**" (`19 * 256 + 14`)

My question is how to automate this into a function - been racking my brains and I can't think of a way to do it.

I need the function to take in a value that I need to send to the exe (i.e. `1000`), and then convert this into a string comprising two integer values. For this `1000` example, int1 would therefore be `[232]` and int2 would be `[3]` (`"+ int1 + int2"`) or (`"+ 232 + 3"`).

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Eh, `value / 256` with `value % 256`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using *modulo arithmetics* (`/` for *integer division* and `%` for *remainder* ), i.e.

```
private static string Encode(int value) {
  return $"+ {value % 256} + {value / 256}";
}
```

Test:

```
// + 232 + 3
Console.WriteLine(Encode(1000));
// + 14 + 19
Console.WriteLine(Encode(4878));
```

In order to *decode back*, you can try using *Linq*:

```
private static int Decode(string value) {
  return value
    .Split(new char[] { '+' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
    .Aggregate((a, s) => s * 256 + a);
}
```

Test:

```
// 4878
Console.WriteLine(Decode("+ 14 + 19"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use modulo (%) and / (division) for that

```
void Chunkify(int value, out int b1, out int b2)
{
    b2 = value / 256;
    b1 = value % 256;
}

// usage

int b1, b2;
Chunkify(1000, out b1, out b2);
var stringToSend = "+" + b1 + "+" + b2; // results in +232+3
Console.WriteLine(">> " + stringToSend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method below will do the trick. Although your requirement is only up to 65000, the method below will also works for value beyond that. (i.e. more than two chunks)

```
public static string Split(int number)
{
    var b = new StringBuilder();
    while(number > 0)
    {
        var v = number % 256;
        if(b.Length > 0)
            b.Append(" ");
        b.Append("+ ");
        b.Append(v);
        number /= 256;
    }

    return b.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            int[] inputs = { 1000, 4878 };

            foreach (int input in inputs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("+ {0} + {1}", (input & 0xFF).ToString(), (input >> 8).ToString());
            }
```